# The action 'Navigate' with payload undefined was not handled by any navigator. ( REACT-NATIVE)

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, navigation, react-navigation

I am trying to build an app with 5 screens , this is my code.
++ ADDED APP.JS

```
// ./App.js

import React from "react";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";

import { MainStackNavigator } from "./Screens/StackNavigator";

import DrawerNavigator from "./Screens/DrawerNavigator";

 const App = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <DrawerNavigator />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
export default App
```

```
*HOMESCREEN.JS*

import React from "react";
import { View, Button, Text, StyleSheet,Image } from "react-native";

const Home = ({navigation}) => {
  return (
    <View style = {styles.firstPage}>
    <View style = {styles.topHeader}><Text style={{fontSize:30}}>WORLD GUIDE</Text></View>
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Image
        style={styles.tinyLogo}
        source={require('../images/curvedArrow.png')}
      />
      <Text> SLIDE RIGHT TO START EXPLORE !</Text>
    </View>
    </View>
  );
};
```

```
*StackNavigator.JS*

import React from "react";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";

import Home from "./HomeScreen";
import Fransa from "./FransaScreen";
import FransaGezi from"./FransaGezi";

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const MainStackNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Page1-Trav" component={FransaGezi}/>
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

const FransaStackNavigator = () => {
    return (
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Fransa" component={Fransa} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    );
  }



export { MainStackNavigator, FransaStackNavigator};
```

```
*FransaScreen.JS*

import React from "react";
import { View, StyleSheet, Text, Image,TouchableOpacity} from "react-native";
import Home from './HomeScreen'
import FransaGezi from './FransaGezi'

const Fransa = ({navigation}) => {
  return (
<View style = {styles.firstPage}>
      <View style = {styles.sectopHeader}>
      <Image
        style={styles.bigImage}
        source={require('../images/eskis.jpg')}
      />
      </View>

      <View style = {styles.botHeader}>
        
        <View style= {styles.firstBoxTop}>
          <View style = {styles.firstBox}>
           <TouchableOpacity onPress={() =>
          navigation.navigate(FransaGezi)
          }>
           <Image source={require('../images/gezi.png')} style = {styles.ImageClass} />
           </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
          
          <View style = {styles.secBox}>
          <TouchableOpacity>
           <Image source={require('../images/food.png')} style = {styles.ImageClass} />
           </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>

        </View>
          
        <View style= {styles.firstBoxBot}>
          <View style = {styles.firstBox}>
          <TouchableOpacity>
           <Image source={require('../images/para.png')} style = {styles.ImageClass} />
           </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
          <View style = {styles.secBox}>
          <TouchableOpacity>
           <Image source={require('../images/popmekan.png')} style = {styles.ImageClass} />
           </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </View>
      
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};
```

```
*DrawerNavigator.JS*

import React from "react";

import { createDrawerNavigator } from "@react-navigation/drawer";

import { FransaStackNavigator } from "./StackNavigator";

import Home from "./HomeScreen";
import FransaGezi from "./FransaGezi";
import Fransa from "./FransaScreen";
import { StackActions } from "@react-navigation/native";
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

const DrawerNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator>
      <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="Fransa" component={FransaStackNavigator} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
}

export default DrawerNavigator;
```

```
*FransaGezi.JS*

import React from "react";
import { View, Button, Text, StyleSheet,Image } from "react-native";

const FransaGezi = ({}) => {
  return (
    <View style = {styles.firstPage}>
    <View style = {styles.topHeader}><Text style={{fontSize:30}}>NOLUR ÇALIŞ</Text></View>
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Image
        style={styles.tinyLogo}
        source={require('../images/curvedArrow.png')}
      />
      <Text> PLEASE WORK  !</Text>
    </View>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Drawer is working without problem, when I click "Fransa" going related page. But when I click first  image in FransaScreen

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() =>
          navigation.navigate(FransaGezi)
          }>
```

I get this error message >>>
The action 'Navigate' with payload undefined was not handled by any navigator.

I know that I am missing some part about StackNavigator screen but when I change it like navigation.navigate(Home) it sends me Home page.
Waiting for your helps thanks a lot :)

Comment: How can this routes comunicate with themselves? You need to wrap all your routes in a NavigationContainer.

Comment: You're passing a component to `navigate` instead of a route name

Comment: @GabrielTiso ` <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Page1-Trav" component={FransaGezi}/>
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer> ` change my code like that if u wanted to say it but it didn't work. It is my first app so I am so new in react that's why I may not understand what u said sorry :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When dealing with routes in React Native, there are some things you have to put in mind. First of all the route types. In your case you are using StackRoutes, so a basic structure for that would be:

A Routes file

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler'

import React from 'react'
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native'
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack'

import { Home } from './pages/Home'
import { Dashboard } from './pages/Dashboard'
import { Details } from './pages/Details'

const AppStack = createStackNavigator()

export const Routes = () => {
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <AppStack.Navigator headerMode='none'>
                <AppStack.Screen name='Home' component={Home} />
                <AppStack.Screen name='Dashboard' component={Dashboard} />
                <AppStack.Screen name='Details' component={Details} />
            </AppStack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    )
}
```

In your app, I can see that you have routes with nested routes. In that case you can simply change your component at the AppStack.Screen, and put your routes there. Example:

```
import DrawerNavigator from 'yout path here'
import FransaGezi from 'your path here too'

// If this is the main Routes component, you should decide what types of navigation you'll use. In this case, let's use a Stack

const AppStack = createStackNavigator()

const Routes = () => {
  return(
    <NavigationContainer>
      <AppStack.Navigator>
        <AppStack.Screen name='Some cool name' component={//here you can put a single component or another routes component, such as DrawerNavigator} />
      </Appstack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
```

To navigate between routes you can simply do that

```
//import this hook in a page you want to navigate

import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native'

//you can then use it in your component

const MyComponent = () => {

   const navigation = useNavigation()

   return (
      <Something onClick={() => navigation.navigate('here you need to put the name prop that you provided in your AppStack.Screen, for example, "Some cool name" as specified up in the Routes)} />
   )
}
```

Plus! If I didn't help you, here's a link to React Navigation. Your doubts will surely be answered there :) [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/)